# how to inject JS Console in to any page? jsconsole.com

Tags: javascript, debugging

For educational purpose, I want to **remotely** debug an application running on my mobile device that I don't have access to the source code, as long as I understand that is possible with http://jsconsole.com direct injection:

> http://jsconsole.com/inject.html
>
> http://jsconsole.com/inject.html?javascript:(function(s){s.src='http://jsconsole.com/inject.js';document.body.appendChild(s)})(document.createElement('script'))

I tried to follow the instructions, I created the bookmaker on my device and everything but I have **no clue** how to make it work, does any one have any idea how it works?

> This page should redirect right away to the correct url, once it does,
>   bookmarket it on your mobile phone, then remove the
>   http://jsconsole.com/inject.html? (including the question mark) part
>   to get the bookmarklet to work.
>
> Alternatively, to inject JS Console, bookmarket this: JS Console and
>   sync to your phone.

For instance, how can I debug remotely this jQueryUI with http://jsconsole.com???:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/default.html

Thanks!

PS, jsconsole screencast http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y219Ziuipvc

Comment: Why not use firebug or firebug lite?

Comment: Did you click on the bookmark that you made?

Comment: @LarryBattle: because there is no way to use firebug on a WebKit mobile browser.

Comment: @Hexxagonal: yes I did, and I got the jsconsole but then how can I remotely debug?

Comment: Note that, at the moment, the bookmarklet for injection is broken due to a file having gone missing in refactoring: https://github.com/remy/jsconsole/issues/75

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've got the jsconsole up and running type the command:

```
:listen
```

to begin remote debugging.

Here's what I did to make this work for me:

1. Go to the console at JSConsole.Com
2. Run the command `:listen` - this generates a unique key for you with a JS url.
3. Copy the url it gives you for the JS file, It looks something like: http://jsconsole.com/remote.js?C180AA15-F9E3-406F-A8F5-F27267DE69C6
4. Open a new browser window and go to the URL you want to debug
5. Paste the following into the browser replacing the URL for the one you generated above: `javascript:(function(s){s.src='http://jsconsole.com/remote.js?C180AA15-F9E3-406F-A8F5-F27267DE69C6';document.body.appendChild(s)})(document.createElement('script'));`
6. Go back to the console window and it'll tell you it's connected:

> Connection established with
>   http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/default.html Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
>   NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19

Comment: where? in the WebKit browser? can you explain more please

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the bookmark.

Click edit in context menu.

Delete `http://jsconsole.com/inject.html?` from it.

Now go to the page you want to analyse and left click on the bookmark. You'll get redirected to http://jsconsole.com/ and now you can do anything with the page you want.. e.g. you can check the title by typing `document.title` and pressing enter.